# Address already in use (Maven site plugin, site:run)

Tags: maven

Seems like the Maven site plugin does not have a command to stop before starting, resulting in an error if the Jetty container is already started (from previous Maven site:run), how may i solve this?

My goal is to be able to see the site on my localhost using the `site:run` Maven command.

[Maven site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1:run (default-cli) on project parameterized-logging-migrator: Error executing Jetty: Address already in use: bind ->
2011-12-21 20:41:11.463::INFO:  Shutdown hook executing
2011-12-21 20:41:11.567::INFO:  Shutdown hook complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mvn site:run](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/run-mojo.html) does not have any option to shutdown an existing jetty server.  If you do not want to manually do this before another run, one possibility is to run it on another port

```
mvn site:run -Dport=8081
```

Comment: Thanks, does it mean if I change this to another port, I do not have to manually stop it?